# Add a certain amount to the 'red' value of RGB to create a sunset affect, help please. (java)

Tags: java, colors, rgb, pixel

Ok, so I want a program that goes through a picture line by line, and adds a certain amount to the red value (RGB) to create a sunset affect. The only problem is that, when you get the different values for red, green, and blue, I cannot add, lets say, 50 to the red value to get a sunset affect. The code below is only the part that is responsible for looping through the lines and changing the pixel values.

```
for(int y=0; y < sunsetPic.getHeight(); y++)                  
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < sunsetPic.getWidth(); x++)             
            {
                targetPixel = sunsetPic.getPixel(x,y);                 
                pixelColor = targetPixel.getColor();                    

                redValue = pixelColor.getRed();
                greenValue = pixelColor.getGreen();
                blueValue = pixelColor.getBlue();

                pixelColor = new Color(redVlue + 50, greenValue, blueValue);
                targetPixel.setColor(pixelColor);                       
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I cannot just add 50 to the redValue to create a sunset affect. Can someone please help me by making a way I can get my sunset affect?

Comment: This is more of a graphics question than a programming question.

Comment: Would increasing it by a fraction of the current value be a more realistic effect?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a sunset effect, you need to do a bit more than add a bit of red.  Odds are good you'll need to remove a bit of green and blue too.  Those removals will likely be proportional removals, leaving a percentage of the original color present.  The most flexible technique to go about this is to use one or more color matrices.  That way you can independently adjust each output color based on a linear combination of the input colors.  Generally, you include the A color, which means that most color matrices are 4x5, with the fifth element being a constant added or subtracted regardless of input.

[A code example is here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/how-to-use-the-color-matrix-to-exchange-the-color-channels-of-an.html), and depending on your need for fidelity, you can tweak the transformation matrix as many times as you like until you get the visual effects you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, load the image into a paint program like Gimp or Photoshop and use that to edit and preview color changes.  Once you get the look you want use the percentages of RGB you arrived at and those will be your runtime changes.

I'd suggest using a multiplier instead of an addition and I'd suggest not boosting your Red above 1.0 but follow Edwin Buck's idea of multiplying down Green and Blue.